# BrowserSync: How can I serve both HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

Can [BrowserSync](https://browsersync.io/) serve both HTTP and HTTPS on different ports?

```
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();

bs.init({
    server: "./app",
    port: 8080
    https: false,
    ....
});
```

According to documentation there is an [option](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-https) for switching protocol to HTTPS. I would like to have both of them: an HTTP on 8080 port and an HTTPS on 8443 port.